# Call to os.setreuid is hanging for any user except root

Tags: python

We're having an issue on a particular server where a call to os.setreuid is hanging, if the uid passed is not the one for the root user.

The code is in this function (please forgive any typos - code is on a different classified system and I'm having to retype it):

```
import os
import pwd

def run_as(username):
    user=pwd.getpwnam(username)
    uid, gid = user.pw_uid, user.pw_gid
    os.initgroups(username, gid)
    os.setregid(gid, gid)
    os.setreuid(uid, uid)
```

It successfully finds the user, gets the uid and gid, calls initgroups, and does the setregid. When the call is made to setreuid, it's hanging. Not returning, but not throwing errors either.

This is on a Redhat Linux server - might be RHEL7 but I think it's RHEL6. It works on other servers. On the problem server, we've checked /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. We've deleted the user and remade it. If we pass "root" as the username, it works. Pass any other user and it hangs. Has anyone ever dealt with anything like this and have any words of wisdom?

Comment: Seems more like an OS question that a Python one. You may want to tag it with other labels, and / or post it on serverfault.com

Comment: Are you certain that it's hanging on the `os.setreuid` call? Does running your script with `strace` yield anything of interest? Is selinux enabled on your system, and if so are there any corresponding errors in your audit logs?

Comment: Yes, it's hanging on the os.setruid call. This is remote development and the person who is actually on the server and can do work is not a developer, so we had him put simple print statements around every line of the function - it prints all but the last one, which is after the os.setreuid call. I don't believe selinux is on the system (but I can check), and we've checked all the logs we can find and no errors are being logged.